# How to play mp3 files via javascript without any html5 feature?

Tags: javascript, audio, browser, mp3

I need to encode an mp3 audio file with base64, then sent to client(web browser), decode it via javascript, then play it.

Is there a way to play an mp3 file via javascript?

Comment: http://cssrevolt.com/upload/files/pimp3/

Comment: @j08691 I get silence on chrome17/linux

Comment: @GGG - funny, I got silence on FF but it worked on chrome.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a flash plugin or java plugin. There is no other way to produce audio without HTML5 features, even if you wrote your own MP3 codec in "pure" JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

[jPlayer](http://www.jplayer.org/) and [SoundManager2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/) are the two main javascript media playback libraries

Answer (score 0):

You can use an object tag. Something like

```
    <object type="audio/mpeg" data="music.mp3">
      <param name="autoplay" value="true">
      No audio player. Please upgrade to a newer browser.
    </object>
```

You will have limited control over the playing of the mp3 and browser support can be spotty, but that should work.